# Employment in France after a master's degree

Tags: working-visas, france

Is it difficult for foreigners over 36 to find a job in France, after acquiring a master's degree there? My wife and I are planning to move to France from India. We already have over a decade of work experience here. We have enrolled into a French university to upskill and find a job in France.

Does anyone know if this is a risk as French companies might prefer younger employees? I know there will not be overt discrimination by age or race, but there could be some underlying trends. We were worried because we have taken a loan for this. We do not speak French now, but are planning to learn it soon.

Comment: What business are you in now and what do you plan to be in? Will your wife work too? What's your plan for work authorization?

Comment: What industry will you work in?

Comment: I have 11 years of experience in digital media services at Technicolor, Deluxe and a few smaller companies. Basically operations, people and project management, on-boarding and transition management. But not academically qualified for these, just through experience and performance, which is why I wanted to get a degree. I will be doing my masters in Marketing. My wife has over 5 years of experience in pharmaceutical companies in QC. She is from a Chemistry background. But basically, it is my idea to look for a job and I plan to be in the same/similar field.

Answer (score 1):

I know for a fact that some large businesses whose current workforce is very unbalanced do prioritize people younger than 30 or 35 (and women) for external recruitment. For qualified jobs, I don't think being a foreigner plays a big role generally but speaking French and having a residence permit certainly does.

The language is really a big issue. For example, I have met people from all sorts of background working in engineering in France but very few who could not speak French.

That said, the job market is currently very open (at least for qualified applicants) so even if it's slightly more difficult, it's not a bad time to try.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on

- in what field you will receive your master degree
- what marks
- what you consider "difficult"
- if you want to work in a specific town in France or if you would be willing to make a job in any part of the country
- your expectations about income

Comment: (-1) You just seem to be basing that on “common“ sense with no particular insight into the French job market. One example : Marks do not matter in the least. Unlike what happens in Germany, French job applications do not include the marks, especially for someone who already has job experience. Nobody will ask, nobody cares, you won't be asked to produce transcripts (or even your diplomas in most cases). The reputation of the school you went to might play a role (even if you were a mediocre student at a “good“ school) but that's it.